# colorbar change text value matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

Given the following code

```
x = np.random.random((50))*2 -1
y = np.random.random((50))
plt.scatter(x,y,c=x**3,cmap='viridis')
cb = plt.colorbar()

#I want a smarter (& working) version of this
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(
    [str(np.cbrt(eval(i.get_text()))) for i in cb.ax.get_yticklabels()]
    )
```

I want to emphasize differences on small scales using `x**3` to set the color in the scatterplot, but I would like to display the value of `x` (not `x**3` like in the shown plot) on the colorbar.

This I believe can be done by changing the labels using the inverse function (here cube-root). The problem with that being that matplotlib typically chooses round values, while this would not, in general, choose such values.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [`FuncFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) from the [`matplotlib.ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = np.random.random((50))*2 -1
y = np.random.random((50))

plt.scatter(x,y,c=x**3,cmap='viridis',vmin=-1,vmax=1)
cb = plt.colorbar()

def label_cbrt(x,pos):
    return "{:4.2f}".format(np.cbrt(x))

cb.formatter = ticker.FuncFormatter(label_cbrt)
cb.update_ticks()

plt.show()
```

[image]